# css does not displaying properly on mobile browser

Tags: html, css

This is [my page](http://www.lokislayer.com/Stuffed_Pepper_Soup.html)

My css for the above web page looks fine on browsers on the desktop, however, on mobile browsers the border around the food ingredients are displayed incorrectly:

Relevant CSS :

```
.page_title {
  text-transform:capitalize;
  text-align:center;
}
.food_list {
  text-transform:capitalize;
}

.listing {
  text-indent:10px;
  margin-right:1500px;
  margin-left:10px;
  color:black;
  background-color:lightblue;
  border-radius: 10px 20px 30px 40px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 20px 30px 40px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 20px 30px 40px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px 20px 30px 40px;
}

.ul {
  list-style:none;
}

p {
  text-transform:none;
}

p span {
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: remove `margin-right:1500px;`, and what your mean about "displayed incorrectly" ?

Comment: The reason why I had margin-right:1500px is so that on a pc browser, the box would not stretch across the whole screen. How could I just have the box just surround the ingredients section on both the pc and mobile browsers??

Comment: You can also refer to CSS3's media query features [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172061/javascript-if-else-statement-with-3-conditions) That can ensure your desired size for both desktop and mobile browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/Fsj46/)

```
.listing {
    text-indent: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: black;
    float: left;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border-radius: 10px 20px 30px 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 20px 30px 40px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 20px 30px 40px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px 20px 30px 40px;
}

h2{
    clear:both;
}
```